# Bash rename files with duplicated file names

Tags: bash, sh

I made a mistake in moving some of my files, and after I moved them, they ended up with duplicated file names with '-' in the middle, for example:

```
Robot arm fails - Robot arm fails.mp4
this-is-another-file - this-is-another-file.txt
document - here - document - here.pdf
```

I would like to remove half of the name: 
eg:

```
Robot arm fails - Robot arm fails.mp4 -> Robot arm fails.mp4

this-is-another-file - this-is-another-file.txt -> this-is-another-file.txt

document - here - document - here.pdf -> document - here.pdf
```

I tried this code:

```
find . -type f -name "*-*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; g="${f/*-/}"; mv -- "$f" "$g"' - '{}' \;
```

But it does not work for files that contain '-' in their name..

Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: where is your code which you tried? Please remember SO is here to help people who attempt to try themselves first!

Comment: I tried this code: `find . -type f -name "*-*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; g="${f/*-/}"; mv -- "$f" "$g"' - '{}' \;` But it removes all chars after '-' which is in the middle. The problem is that it does not work for files that contain more than one '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash, it's easy:

```
for fname in *; do
  # remove extension
  name="${fname%.*}"
  # extract the half and append extension
  echo mv -- "$fname" "${name::${#name}/2-1}.${fname##*.}"
done
```

If its output looks good, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a the `awk` solution. Similar to bash solution:

#### script.awk

```
{
    split($0,fileParts, "\\.[^.]*$", ext); # split file to fileParts and extension
    newFileName = "'" substr(fileParts[1], 1, length(fileParts[1]) / 2 - 1) ext[1]"'"; # new fileName is: half fileParts and append extension
    cmd = "mv '" $0 "' " newFileName; # create a rename bash commmand from origin file name ($0) and newFileName
    print cmd; # print bash command (for debug)
    #system(cmd); # execute bash command
}
```

This is a debug version that will print the rename command and not execute.

To execute after checking the correctness. Replace `#system` with `system`, and run again.

#### running:

```
find . -type f -name "*-*" | awk -f script.awk
```